# Session null in _Layout.cshtml MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, razor

I just created a demo MVC application. It has two controllers, `HomeController` and `ContactController`.
Here is the `HomeController` code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Session["Username"] = "Admin User";
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here is the `ContactController` :

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here is the `_Layout.cshtml` code where I'm displaying the `Session["Username"]`:

```
   <div class="float-left">
       <p class="site-title">@Session["Username"].ToString()</p>
   </div>
```

Now, once I have hosted the application the default `Home/Index` gets called and the session variable is set. Next, when I load the `Contact/Index` controller method, it displays an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

at this line `<p class="site-title">@Session["Username"].ToString()</p>`

This error occurs frequently. Any one knows what I'm missing ?

Comment: I have the problem like this, once, so I've created the `ApplicationBaseController` inherited from `Controller`, then override the `OnActionExecuted` function and then I was setting the `UserName` value in that method. (All my controllers inherited from `ApplicationBaseController`)

Comment: Could it be because you set the Session to Admin User in the index action of HomeController but not in the Index action of Contact controller? Have you tried the same line of code for index action in the contact controller?

Comment: @SeM then how to show the Session in cshtml ?

Comment: @iJade Store it in `ViewData`.

Comment: @SeM but inside the OnActionExecuted would I be able to set ViewData from Session ? Would be helpful if you can show me a code sample

Comment: @iJade Yes sure, I've added an answer.

Comment: Did you inspect the `Session` value inside `Contact/Index` action?

Comment: @SamGhatak it's not there. I inspected.

Answer (score 0):

**Create `ApplicationBaseController`:**

```
public class ApplicationBaseController : Controller
{
    public ApplicationBaseController()
    {

    }
    protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //Define your UserName
        Session["Username"] = "Admin User";
        //Some code if you want to add
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

**Inherit your controllers from `ApplicationBaseController`:**

```
public class HomeController : ApplicationBaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class ContactController : ApplicationBaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**In `_Layout.cshtml`:**

```
<div class="float-left">
   <p class="site-title">@Session["Username"]</p>
</div>
```

### UPDATE:

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Define your UserName
        Session["Username"] = "Admin User";
        return View();
    }
}
```

**In `_Layout.cshtml`:**

```
<div class="float-left">
   <p class="site-title">@Session["Username"]</p>
</div>
```

if it not works(because for me it works correctly), please provide whole `_layout.cshtml` code and the `Index.cshtml` code

Comment: Ok ... Assume I have a Login logic in the `Home/Index` after which only I'll be able to set ` Session["Username"]` .The how to do that. Since in your code you are setting the Session in the BaseController ?

Comment: @iJade How do you Login your users, do you use Identity framework or something custom?

Comment: It's a simple db call with the username and password for validation. if validated I'll keep the username in the Session.

Comment: Well it's not working that way.Please have a look at the question code. I'm already doing the way you said. I'm setting the username in Session in `Home/Index` but when I redirect to `Contact/Index` the Session becomes null resulting in object reference error in _Layout.cshtml page. Note : I'm facing the issue frequently after I have hosted the application

Comment: can we continue in chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112999/room-for-ijade-and-sem